# How to shorten code or store it in a data file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, database, csv

I am trying to create a feature on my website that prints out values in input boxes after an item from the dropdown menu is selected. Currently, my code works, but it is just too lengthy. Below is the JavaScript code that I would like to shorten or stored in a data file.

```
function dropdownTip(element){

      if(element == "Methane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="190.6";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="45.99";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.012";
      }
      else if(element == "Ethane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="305.3";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="48.72";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.100";
      }
      else if(element == "Propane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="369.8";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="48.48";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.152";
      }
      else if(element == "n-Butane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="425.1";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="37.96";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.200";
      }
      else if(element == "n-Pentane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="469.7";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="33.70";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.252";
      }
      else if(element == "n-Hexane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="507.6";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="30.25";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.301";
      }
      else if(element == "n-Heptane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="540.2";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="27.40";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.350";
      }
      else if(element == "n-Octane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="568.7";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="24.90";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.400";
      }
      else if(element == "n-Nonane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="594.6";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="22.90";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.444";
      }
      else if(element == "n-Decane") {
        document.getElementById("myText").value="617.7";
        document.getElementById("myText1").value="21.10";
        document.getElementById("myText2").value="0.492";
      }
```

The code is actually way longer than this. The `else if(element== "x") {}` lines actually extend for another 390 lines.

Comment: It good to hear that you want to improve your code. You can create .txt file with each product in new line (e.g. `Methane 190.6 45.99 0.012`.) Then load and split this file by delimeter (in my example space). You can also use static array or provider class with said array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the values in a array of objects and use it something like this `obj[element]['text']`

```js
var obj = {
       "methane" : {"text":"190.6","text1":"45.99","text2":"0.012"},
       "eethane" : {"text":"305.3","text1":"48.72","text2":"0.100"}
}

function dropdownTip(element){
      if(element) {
      console.log(obj[element]['text'],obj[element]['text1'],obj[element]['text2']);
        /*document.getElementById("myText").value=obj[element]['text'];
        document.getElementById("myText1").value=obj[element]['text1'];
        document.getElementById("myText2").value=obj[element]['text2'];*/
        
        
      }
 }
 
 dropdownTip("methane")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an object indexed by `element`, whose values are arrays of `#myText`, `#myText1`, `#myText2` values:

```
const elementValues = {
  Methane: [190.6, 45.99, 0.012],
  Ethane: [305.3, 48.72, '0.100'], // you'll need to use strings for trailing zeros
  Propane: [369.8, 48.48, 0.152],
  'n-Butane': [425.1, 37.96, '0.200'],
  // ...
}
function dropdownTip(element){
  const possibleArr = elementValues[element];
  if (possibleArr) {
    ['myText', 'myText1', 'myText2'].forEach(
      (id, i) => document.getElementById(id).value = possibleArr[i]
    );
  }
}
```

You might consider using classes instead of IDs, which would make the code a bit simpler:

```
const elementValues = {
  Methane: [190.6, 45.99, 0.012],
  Ethane: [305.3, 48.72, '0.100'], // you'll need to use strings for trailing zeros
  Propane: [369.8, 48.48, 0.152],
  'n-Butane': [425.1, 37.96, '0.200'],
  // ...
}
function dropdownTip(element){
  const possibleArr = elementValues[element];
  if (possibleArr) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.myText').forEach((elm, i) => {
      elm.value = possibleArr[i];
    });
  }
}
```

```js
const elementValues = {
  Methane: [190.6, 45.99, 0.012],
  Ethane: [305.3, 48.72, '0.100'], // you'll need to use strings for trailing zeros
  Propane: [369.8, 48.48, 0.152],
  'n-Butane': [425.1, 37.96, '0.200'],
  // ...
}
function dropdownTip(element){
  const possibleArr = elementValues[element];
  if (possibleArr) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.myText').forEach((elm, i) => {
      elm.value = possibleArr[i];
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input onchange="dropdownTip(this.value)">

<br>

<input class="myText"></div>
<input class="myText"></div>
<input class="myText"></div>
```

If you don't like the bracket notation, another option is to write a long multiline string, which you transform into an object afterwards:

```
const elementValuesStr = `
Methane 190.6 45.99 0.012
Ethane 305.3 48.72, 0.100
Propane 369.8 48.48 0.152
n-Butane 425.1 37.96, 0.200
...
`;
const elementValues = elementValuesStr
  .trim()
  .split('\n')
  .reduce((a, line) => {
    const [key, ...vals] = line.match(/\S+/g);
    a[key] = vals;
    return a;
  }, {});
```

And then you can use the same code as above, using `elementValues`.

```js
const elementValuesStr = `
Methane 190.6 45.99 0.012
Ethane 305.3 48.72, 0.100
Propane 369.8 48.48 0.152
n-Butane 425.1 37.96, 0.200
`;
const elementValues = elementValuesStr
  .trim()
  .split('\n')
  .reduce((a, line) => {
    const [key, ...vals] = line.match(/\S+/g);
    a[key] = vals;
    return a;
  }, {});
console.log(elementValues);
```

Comment: `['n-Butane']:` too much over engineered.

Comment: Oh, I guess so. I suppose a big multiline string would be a bit easier

Comment: no, i means the computed property for just a key without a variable.

Comment: None of the code really worked. The first snippet came the closest to working, but it only prints out "undefined."

Comment: @LunaPark I edited another snippet into the question to demonstrate - press "Run code snippet" to see it working. Eg, put in "Methane" and the other inputs get populated with `109.6`, `45.99`, `0.012`